# Error :Could not load dll.Error value 193

Tags: c++, windows, mobile

Can anyone tell me the cause of this error?
 Error:Could not load dll.Error value 193

I am trying to load the dll (I am using VS2005,C++ is the language) into the device(windows mobile) and execute it.
When i do this , I get an error as said above.

Comment: We'll need more to go on than this.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly stupid answer, but has the DLL been built for the specific OS version and architecture of the device you're running it on.  e.g.  Windows Mobile 7, ARM.  If it's a desktop DLL, or a DLL for a different architecture (e.g. MIPS versus ARM), it will not work.  If its the right architecture but different version it may not work (e.g. Windows Mobile 6 DLL on Windows Mobile 5).

Comment: There is no mismatch in the version which is built and used.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem while I load other dlls.

Comment: If it's a DLL that you have source for, why not compile it as a static lib and link it into your main EXE?  If you don't have the source, what tools are you using to check the validity of the DLL for your platform?